# Dates not recognized as Dates, despite format

Tags: excel, datetime

I have imported a column with many dates, but Excel will NOT read them as dates for some reason.  I have looked around and tried doing ["Text to Columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660906/some-dates-recognized-as-dates-some-dates-not-recognized-why) and using "DMY" format.  I have also tried simply changing the format of the cells to Date (also Custom 'dd/mm/yyyy'), but nothing works.

Here's what the dates look like (Column A):

```
09/17/2013
09/05/2013
11/11/2013
11/11/2013
12/29/2013
11/15/2013
12/04/2013
12/04/2013
12/04/2013
12/12/2013
12/04/2013
```

And I am trying to determine the month(), day(), and year() but nothing works.  If I do =Month(a1) it returns January for all of the dates, regardless.  However, =Year(a1) returns the correct year...why is month not working?

I have even tried a helper column to split up the dates into simple text, using a formula like =left(A1,search("/",A1)) but that returns a #VALUE error!

What is preventing Excel from seeing these as dates, so I can treat them as such?  Thanks for any help or advice!!

Edit:  When changing the date to the "Number" format, Excel 'correctly' changes the date format to the numerical 411928 type, so I know at SOME level it knows it's a date.  I have then done Text to Columns, using "/" as delimiter, and split the data into three columns.  In a fourth column, I combined the splits via =Date(A3,A1,A2) [for 'date(year,month,day)'] but then when I paste that back into the spreadsheet, still can't use =month()...

Comment: Are they naturally left- or right-justified?  Try =A1*1 and fill down - what happens?

Comment: With a date being in A1, putting =A1*1 in B1 returns the date again.  I think they're naturally right justified

Comment: Does =month(A1*1) work?

Comment: Yes! That works.  Is that because using the `*1` forces the text to become numerical, which Excel can then work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=month(A1*1) works because, as you guessed, the *1 turns the text into a number.  I think the problem may be rooted in the format of the file you are importing.  There may be non-printing characters in it?  Or maybe it's an issue caused by US / European dates (this is in line with the month causing most of the problems)?  Although without looking at the data I'm just guessing.

One way to immediately see whether a value is being treated as text or numeric is that numbers align right and text aligns left.  You will need to first double check that any alignment formatting has been removed though.

Comment: I'm almost positive it's right aligned, without any other formatting.  I think it's, as you mentioned, the US/EU date style. The spreadsheet with those dates is created by a colleague in Europe - so I assume that Excel has (deeply embedded somewhere) the date format to be European, and I have yet to find a quick and easy way to tell MY excel that those are European style, and to switch to USA (even doing Format, and Date, and choosing US).  This works, so thank you very much!