# Problems with SUMIFS in Excel when using external reference

Tags: excel, sumifs

After doing a lot of research and trying various potential solutions, I am still stuck and hoping someone may be able to point me on the right track.

I am using a SUMIFS function in an Excel 2010 spreadsheet, but whilst it works when the reference spreadsheet is open, it gives a #VALUE error when the reference spreadsheet is closed.

My searching so far has identified that this is a known issue with Excel, but though I have tried various workarounds that are posted on forums, I haven't been able to make any work. I don't get a #VALUE error, but instead I get a zero.

The original formula is as follows:

```
=SUMIFS('P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$N:$N,'P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$R:$R,$B2,'P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$G:$G,$C2,'P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$J:$J,"pri")
```

As I say, this works fine when the other workbook is open (it obviously drops the "P:\Performance\" pre-fix), but not when it is closed (though it does change the reference to the full path).

So as per other suggestions, I have tried using SUMPRODUCT...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$R:$R=$B2),--('P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$G:$G=$C2),--('P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$J:$J="pri"),('P:\Performance\[All calls.xlsm]Jan 2016'!$N:$N)
```

However, this results in zero, which is clearly incorrect as the SUMIFS version and open workbook gives me a non-zero value.

Working through the calculation steps, I *suspect* it may have something to do with the reference cells themselves being based on formulae, but I'm not certain. Incidentally, I get the same result whether the reference workbook is open or closed.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

PS: I also looked at the Microsoft support site, but although it gives the impression that there is a workaround on the site, the hyperlink leads you back to the same place...
[How to correct a #VALUE! error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-sumif-sumifs-function-e65ce689-978e-44b1-a649-160ed5f13b5a)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect). Or other similar questions on this site.

Comment: A possible explanation is that functions such as SUMIFS have a more 'lenient' approach to mismatched datatypes. For example, assuming columns G and R contain numerics, then, if B2 and C3 also contain numerics, the results of the two formulas will be equal. But, change the entry in cell B2 to the TEXT entry 2 (e.g. by preceding it with an apostrophe) and the SUMPRODUCT version will now return 0, whereas the SUMIFS version will 'helpfully' interpret that text entry as the number 2 and still give the same (non-zero) result. Suggest you clarify your post with the datatypes of all ranges concerned.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first of all thanks to the two people who commented. I didn't need to take a look at the suggested "similar question", because I managed to resolve it myself.

The SUMPRODUCT solution posted elsewhere did in fact work. The issue turned out to be a strange situation with one of the columns I was referencing. On closer examination, I discovered that although the column was formatted as "short date", for some reason, some of the entries were not being recognised as such. I have no idea why this was, but when I converted the column to "number", it was obvious, as some of the dates failed to turn into date numbers. Strange, as all the entries were being created by a formula. So this was why the SUMPRODUCT formula was returning a zero very time.

Anyway, I found the solution here...

[Some dates recognized as dates, some dates not recognized. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660906/some-dates-recognized-as-dates-some-dates-not-recognized)

I have no idea why this worked, but it did. And now the SUMPRODUCT workaround works, with the target spreadsheet closed. Maybe this will help someone else, or maybe it won't, but it does pay to check and double check the format of any cells you are referencing.